# Replication with different column names

Tags: mysql

As MySQL accepts to replicate tables from the Master to the Replicas having different column names, how can I guarantee the consistency of the database?

What happens if one of the replicas with different column names has to be promoted to master through a failover process?

Is there a configuration variable that prevents replication to succeed if this happens?

There are variables that allow you to configure the data conversion, but I can't find anything regarding the different column names.

I would appreciate if someone answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL also allows the tables on the replica to have different indexes, different constraints, different partitioning, or be stored in a different storage engine.

There are legitimate cases where you might want to customize tables on the replica. For example, it might have an advantage if you have a specific query workload you want to run on the replica. But it probably isn't going to go well if you promote the replica to be a source. The performance of queries against that table will have different strengths and weaknesses.

If you need the replica to be ready to take over after a promotion, it's your responsibility to make sure the tables are the same.

As far as I know, there aren't any configuration options to guarantee this. It's up to you — just don't alter the tables on the replica.

Comment: Hi Bill.

Of course, it is my responsibility as I'm the DBA, but I'm trying to establish some control. In my company, we are 10 DBAs and many people (due to lack of control in the company, they have superuser rights).

Comment: You're describing a difficulty with people working as a team and complying with a policy. MySQL can't help with that.